# DocumentDB: Performance impact of built-in string functions (like UPPER)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In our .NET application we use the DocumentDB SDK to query our Azure DocumentDB. 
We were trying to find the cause of a performance problem when we realized that the built-in string functions in queries seems to have a big impact on performance.

I was going to paste some stats that I got from our application but I've been able to replicate the situation with the playground here:
https://www.documentdb.com/sql/demo (click on the sandbox tab)

With the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM food 
WHERE food.description="Babyfood, dessert, fruit pudding, orange, strained"
```

I get:

[image: Query with no UPPER function]

And with `UPPER` string function:

```
SELECT *
FROM food 
WHERE UPPER(food.description)=UPPER("Babyfood, dessert, fruit pudding, orange, strained")
```

I get:

[image: Query with UPPER string function]

The absolute numbers don't really matter here, in our application we apply `UPPER` on an email field and we see a big difference. Operation takes 1s with no `UPPER` vs 20s with it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a few exceptions, any time you use functions on field values it can't use indexes so the query becomes a full table scan. The best way around this is to store the values in another field already UPPER and query against that. Alternatively, if you can combine a more highly selective clause with an UPPER() clause you'll get better performance.

Comment: It's surprising that the docs doesn't mention that, they list examples using those functions in queries... https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/#_built-in-functions Before I mark your answer as accepted do you have any source/link about the behavior ?

Comment: DocumentDB team member here. When you have a query that uses an equality (= "a@b.com") or a range query (>=, <=, >, <) the query engine can use the index because the data is stored in prefix order in the index, same as requested in the query. STARTSWITH and BETWEEN are equivalent, so they also work the same way. This behavior is true of almost all databases, not just DocumentDB. Queries that perform additional transformations via UPPER or check for CONTAINS etc. need to scan all entries, and cannot use the index. The workaround suggested by Larry is the best way to handle this.

Comment: Yes, this is a problem with all databases. Functions on fields result in table scans.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info, perfect answer.