# Does the presence of a single UPPER in CosmosDb SQL Queries force a full collection scan on partition?

Tags: performance, azure-cosmosdb

Given the following SQL, the ManufacturerIdUpperCase is the partition key, and a lower cased value is passed as a hint to direct Cosmos to the correct partition. The "boat.OwnerIdUpperCase" in an indexed property. Will Cosmos use the ownerId to narrow the scan to the subset of documents for this owner, or does the use of the other two UPPER calls require a full collection scan?

```
SELECT * FROM boat 
WHERE boat.ManufacturerIdUpperCase= @ManufacturerId
AND UPPER(boat.Owner.Type)= UPPER(@OwnerType) 
AND boat.OwnerIdUppererCase= @BoatOwnerId) 
AND UPPER(boat.BoatType) = UPPER(@BoatType)
```

I'm trying to decide if I need to maintain a lowercase copy of every property included in the various WHERE clauses, or, if I can do this for one of the remaining UPPER conversions on an indexed property that will reduce the scope of the dataset such that a scan is only required on the resulting subset, not the entire partition?

I've read the old posts like the one below, and run the SQL in the sandbox as proposed. In the simple scenario, I am seeing the same result as the author. However, my work scenario is more complex as described above.

[DocumentDB: Performance impact of built-in string functions (like UPPER)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517296/documentdb-performance-impact-of-built-in-string-functions-like-upper/40517466#40517466)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Victor, welcome to StackOverflow! I am from the Cosmos DB engineering team.

In this particular query, since all the filter predicates are intersections (ANDs), and not unions (ORs), Cosmos DB will narrow down the set of documents to evaluate and will not do a full scan. Please ensure that all the 4 fields (/ManufacturerIdUpperCase, /Owner/Type, /OwnerIdUppererCase, /BoatType) are indexed (added as part of "includedPaths" in the indexingPolicy).

Comment: Why is it required to have all 4 fields be indexed? I would assume just `/OwnerIdUppererCase` would suffice. Can the execution engine somehow use multiple indexes for the same query execution? Over `UPPER(X)`? :O

Comment: The execution engine will use whatever indexes are available for the same query execution. So both the equality predicates (without the UPPER) will utilize the index efficiently, and UPPER/LOWER will also utilize the index, although less efficiently (the evaluation engine will degrade this to an existence check of the property on the index).

Comment: The system i inherited has 19 indexes, apparently every field that UPPER is applied to. Each index uses the same Range settings shown below and the indexingMode is consistent, automatic = true, Is this a viable strategy to get around full collection scans? I'm guessing no but will test
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "Number",
                    "precision": -1
                },
                {
                    "kind": "Range",
                    "dataType": "String",
                    "precision": -1
                }

Comment: Yes, this is viable. Please ensure all the filter predicates that appear in your queries (not only those that are part of an UPPER clause) are indexed in this same way. As long as there are more selective predicates in a query apart from the UPPER predicates, the query wouldn't do a full scan.